# Weird result using LogFont with AntiAliased or ClearType

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I want to use a custom font on a Windows CE 5 device. It works, but it doesn't look that good. So I tried to see if it would be any better with anti-aliasing or ClearType enabled. Instead, it's even worse. Just to be sure I tried enabling it for the default font, Tahoma, but it's not any better.

Using the instructions on http://inthehand.com/blogs/peterfoot/archive/2008/04/02/antialisasing-and-netcf.aspx, at the left is the expected result and at the right is the result I'm getting.

[image: expected result] [image: real result]

Has anyone had this problem before, and if so how did you solve it?

Comment: Does anti aliasing "improve" the default system fonts/text?  For example, do the icon labels on the desktop or the text in Explorer improve, or does it also get worse?

Comment: And I'm assuming you did, in fact, enable ClearType? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms901097.aspx

Comment: @ctacke I've added the key, rebooted the device, and confirmed the key is still there. Makes no difference in the application. Desktop and Explorer show no improvement nor do they look worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the desktop and explorer show no difference when ClearType is enabled, that indicates that ClearType, and probably anti-aliasing is not supported by your device's OS and/or display driver.

What that's leading to when you use code that tries to use anti-aliasing is GDI sending data to the display driver that it doesn't "understand" how to render so it gets rendered incorrectly.

Go back to your OEM and ask if they have an OS image that has anti-aliasing/ClearType support (unlikely if the image you have doesn't) and maybe ask them to add/implement it (it might be as simple for them as setting SYSGEN_GPE_CLEARTYPE in the build).

Comment: I'm already talking to my OEM, I'l pass along the information you gave. Thank you.